# Incrustar una aplicación dentro de una Ventana WPF

Tags: c#, windows, wpf, interfaz-gráfica

Buenas a toda la comunidad. Primero que todo estoy trabajando en Visual Studio 2015, en C#, realizando un proyecto con WPF, bastante complejo por sus requerimientos. Uno de ellos es poder cargar un programa y que este programa se incruste dentro de una ventada de mi aplicación.

[Aquí](http://www.elguille.info/NET/dotnet/setParentNET.aspx) encontré un ejemplo, el cual funciona perfectamente, el problema es que es para Windows Forms, mientras que mi necesidad es para WPF.

Lo que llevo hasta ahorita es lo siguiente:

Buscar el proceso del programa externo por medio del nombre y devuelve una clase `IntPtr`

```
public static IntPtr getWindow(string titleName)
{
            Process[] pros = Process.GetProcesses(".");
            foreach (Process p in pros)
                if (p.MainWindowTitle.ToUpper().Contains(titleName.ToUpper()))
                    return p.MainWindowHandle;
            return new IntPtr();
}
```

La clase `IntPtr` de la ventada WPF la obtengo por medio de la siguiente Instrucción:

```
IntPtr ptr = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, tengo las dos clases IntPtr, ninguna me devuelve 0.

Ahora bien, en el ejemplo que encontré ([Aquí vuelvo a poner el link](http://www.elguille.info/NET/dotnet/setParentNET.aspx)), se utiliza la segunda instrucción, para indicarle a los diferentes componentes su relación padre-hija o contenedor-contenido.

```
// Hace que una ventana sea hija (o esté contenida en otra)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
```

Al parecer en Windows Forms es simple como ejecutar esa instrucción y hacer ajustes en el tamaño de la aplicación hija, pero en WPF no me está funcionando. Alguien me podría dar una guía o mostrar un ejemplo o un link en donde se logre crear esa relación de ventana contenida y contenedora entre mi aplicación y una aplicación de un tercero, pero con tecnología WPF.

De ante mano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenos días, ya encontré la respuesta, el hecho no es solo asignarle al padre la ventana hija, sino que también se debe de ubicar en la posición de la ventana, darle un tamaño y finalmente repintar la ventana, por suerte, también existe un método que hace todo lo anterior, facilitando la tarea.

Aquí dejo el código:

```
// Cambia el tamaño y la posición de una ventana
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public extern static int MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y,
   int nWidth, int nHeight, int bRepaint);
```

Función completa para asignar al padre la ventana hija y repintar

```
public void IncrustarApp()
{
  hWndApp = ScreenFuntion.getWindow("Notepad");
  if (hWndApp.ToInt32() > 0)
  {
     ProgramsEncrustForm.MoveWindow(hWndApp,0, 0, Int32.Parse(Width.ToString()),
     Int32.Parse(Height.ToString()), 1);
     ProgramsEncrustForm.SetParent(hWndApp, new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
  }
  else
  {
    hWndApp = IntPtr.Zero;
  }
  this.Show();
}
```